# Why Copy operation in Microsoft products(CTRL+C) is overridden by Delete operation(SHIFT+DEL)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ms-word

Today, I copied 2 lines of code in Visual Studio(using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Then deleted one line of commented code somewhere in the class(using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>). Now if I try to paste the copied lines using (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), it is pasting the commented code not the copied lines of code. That means <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> is overriding the clipboard copied items done earlier.
Here I could understand that this could be to give a chance to restore permanently deleted items. Any thoughts on this?

This same behavior is replicated in other Microsoft products like:
1. MS-Word application (by copying, deleting(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and then pasting some statements).
2. Windows files (by copying, deleting(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and then pasting some files).

Comment: `Shift+Del` is a shortcut for the *Cut* clipboard command. This isn't specific to Microsoft products either. You'll notice it in *most* applications. In fact, the `Ctrl+Ins`, `Shift+Ins` and `Shift+Del` keystrokes *predate* Windows. They were part of [IBM's CUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) standard. The `Ctrl+C`, 'Ctrl-X' etc keystrokes come from [Xerox PARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C).

Answer (score 4):

`Shift+Del` is a shortcut for the Cut clipboard command. This isn't specific to Microsoft products either. It's a keyboard shortcut provided by Windows itself and works in most applications.

In fact, the `Ctrl+Ins`, `Shift+Ins` and `Shift+Del` keystrokes predate Windows. They were part of [IBM's CUA standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access), the only actual standard about keyboard shortcuts. Back then, every application used its own shortcuts forcing people to memorize them.

The `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl-X`, `Ctrl+V` keystrokes come from [Xerox PARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) and were never an actual standard. Apple used them though and Microsoft added them to Windows. A *lot* of people complained that Microsoft was abandoning a proven standard.

By the early 2000s Windows and Mac OS were the only windowing OS's left so the Xerox PARC shortucts prevailed.

Comment: My understanding for Shift+Del command have been to permanently delete the code/item. Not sure how to react with new understanding that it is a shortcut for the Cut clipboard command rather permanently delete.

Comment: @WpfBee Shift+Delete to permanently delete is, as far as I know, only doing that in Windows Explorer... But I confirm what Panagiotis says: I lived and worked in those times.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.